# Visual Studio only shows active project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Stupid question but how to you configure the solution explorer to show all projects in the directory?  I reinstalled and currently the solution explorer only shows the active project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is meant to only show one solution per instance, but you can also open another instance with your other solution(s). All projects have to have there config file and be in the same directory as your solution file to be able to view them. A picture would help to portray your actual problem. You might find this helpful: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx

Comment: Basically, in netbeans or eclipse the project explorer shows all the projects I have in my workspace directory.

In eclipse, the explorer shows only my current project and does not list any other projects I have in my workspace directory.

Comment: @Spectral are you talking about Eclipse or Visual Studio, because your question states Visual Studio. A project in VS is not the same as a project in Eclipse. The equivalent to a project in Eclipse, in VS is called a solution and a solution can have multiple projects. And as mentioned, you can only view ONE solution in VS per instance.